Changing Subject Line for Content Builder Asset Doesn't Update For Send Definition
I am currently using the REST API provided by Salesforce.
I am updating the Content Builder Asset using PATCH endpoint /asset/v1/content/assets/.
Is there any way for me to update the subject line on the send definitions that use this email template? It seems that the email content body is successfully updated but not the subject line.
I tried using PATCH endpoint /messaging/v1/email/definitions/ to refresh it with the new subject line but it says it can't find definition with external id. However, it works for GET endpoint /messaging/v1/email/definitions/ so I'm confused. I have all the permissions that are necessary.
Also, GET endpoint /messaging/v1/email/definitions/ does not show the list of current definitions. It says there are none in the definitions list.
Please let me know if you have any solutions. Thank you in advance!
